# Symfony2 nginx issue - all pages 404 not found and occurred while loading the web debug toolbar

Tags: symfony, nginx

I've got problem with my project in symfony2 when i'm trying to run this on nginx.

www.domain/ works fine

www.domain/app_dev.php ，"An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found).Do you want to open the profiler?"

www.domain/app.php/someurl/ - 404 not found

/etc/nginx/site-available/example.com

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/adwords-up;
    index app_dev.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name adwords-up.test;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Symfony2 web dir is /web, so you should try `root /var/www/adwords-up/web`